# Custom configuration file for different solution projects

Tags: c#, app-config, desktop-application

I have more than one solution projects for an application with using one app.config for each solution.

Can i do a separate configuration file (other than app.config) for common setting like db name (connection string) ?
Because currently i put these setting in each and every app.config file.

Comment: You ca create your own config file. Just create an XML with all your desired settings.

Comment: (cont'd) If you're concerned about privacy, you can embed your custom XML inside your application. The connection string will not be exposed but you'll have to recompile each time it changes.

Comment: Thanks Andrei.

Can you send any code snippets

Because we can get any key from App.config file using

ConfigurationHelper.Instance.GetAppSettingValueByKey("TestKey").ToString()

but how can get key-values from custom config file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following.

1. Create one config called **"common.config"** like below which will be common to all solutions and let's say it's located @ "E:/myconfig". Please keep all common setting in this config.

   <appSettings>
               <add key="connstring" value="conn string value" />
        </appSettings>
2. Now link this common config in you specific solution config lets say web.config using [**file attribute**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903313%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

   <configuration>

   <appSettings **file="E:\myconfig\Common.config"**>
       <add key="key1" value="value" />

   </appSettings>

</configuration>

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks Mit, but we can get any key from App.config file using ConfigurationHelper.Instance.GetAppSettingValueByKey("TestKey").ToString() but how can get key-values ?

Comment: Yes,you can get the key-value pairs from common config in same way as you are doing from web.config nothing different.

Comment: But this file **"Common.config"** (as you suggested) is not available in _bin\debug_ or _bin\release_ folder so How can it pick these values ?

Comment: No. But at run-time it will be combined into single configuration app-setting object in memory.

Comment: Please look at this for more info. http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/969/external-appsetting-file-for-your-appsettings-in-config-file

Comment: And How can I put connection strings in this "Common.config" file?

Comment: You have to use key-value pairs for connectionstrings like <appSettings> <add key="connstring" value="conn string value" /> </appSettings> in common.config. You could not use separate section for <connectionStrings> in common config just like regular app.config or web.config.